# how do i add delay to a specific animation so it doesnt interfere with another?

Tags: javascript, html, css

so i have a hamburger menu where i want a different animation on its hover and another when its opened, and since i want the lines to slide one after another i added some delay to the slide animation but it applies to the opening/closing animation too.
is there a way to only add delay to the lines on hover without affecting the opening animation?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.toggle-button').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('open')
  });
});
```

```css
.toggle-button {
  width: 24px;
  height: 29px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 64px;
  position: fixed;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 101;
}

.toggle-button:hover span {
  animation-name: spanSlide;
}

@keyframes spanSlide {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0%)
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateX(100%)
  }
  51% {
    transform: translateX(-100%)
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0%)
  }
}

.toggle-button:hover span:nth-child(1) {
  animation: spanSlide 1s linear;
}

.toggle-button:hover span:nth-child(2) {
  animation: spanSlide 1s linear 0.1s;
}

.toggle-button:hover span:nth-child(3) {
  animation: spanSlide 1s linear 0.2s;
}

.toggle-button span {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  height: 1px;
  width: 100%;
  background: black;
  opacity: 1;
  left: 0;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  z-index: 102;
}

.toggle-button span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 1px;
  transform-origin: left center;
}

.toggle-button span:nth-child(2) {
  top: 11px;
  transform-origin: left center;
}

.toggle-button span:nth-child(3) {
  top: 22px;
  transform-origin: left center;
}

.toggle-button.open span:nth-child(1) {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  background-color: #blue;
  width: 40px;
  animation: none;
  animation-delay: none;
}

.toggle-button.open span:nth-child(2) {
  width: 0%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .1s;
  background-color: #blue;
  animation: none;
  animation-delay: none;
}

.toggle-button.open span:nth-child(3) {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  background-color: #blue;
  width: 40px;
  animation: none;
  animation-delay: none;
}

.toggle-button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="toggle-button">
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an event "onmouseover={()=>function_Hover()}" for your menu.
Then, in your function_Hover(), you can use the "setTimeout(function_Delay(), 3000)" method which will activate the function_Delay() function after 3000ms